# problem receiving data from post in php

Tags: php, jquery

This is my called by post to mi php in the server

```
    $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "services/ModelsService.php",
            data: "{IdModelo: "+$("#brand").val()+"}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(values){
                //do something
            }   
    });
```

Now when i'm going to uses the value send from the js. always failed appears blank. But the data it's sending good because when i debug the called with `charles debugging proxy` works well the request

[image: the image]

this is my php file

```
$json = json_decode($_POST,true);
echo $json[1]; //this bring me always blank
```

What i'm doing wrong in my code

Comment: Any reason you're sending pure JSON via POST instead of a key-value representation of it?

Comment: You could always var_dump($json); to see what's in there too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $json['IdModelo'];
```

This is how you get it.

Passing the second argument `true` to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) will return an associative array so you should access array values using associative (string) index.

Comment: Singh hi, and thanks for asking i tried but it doesn't work, i don't know why i'm doing wrong